# Code igniter active record - inserting into a Point column

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, geometry

I have a table with the following schema in MySql 5.1:

```
Venue (id, name, location)
```

where location is of type Point.
I am trying to insert a new record using the CodeIgniter 2.0 active records:

```
$row = array("id" => $id, "name" => $name, "location" => 
"GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)')" );

$this->db->insert('Venues', $row);
```

but i get the following error:

> Cannot get geometry object from data
>   you send to the GEOMETRY field

Comment: Try echoing the query that is being run using $this->db->last_query();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->db->set("id",$id);
$this->db->set("name",$name);
$this->db->set("location",'geomfromtext("POINT(1 1)")',false);
$this->db->insert("Venues");
```